# Linux ACLs lists

Tags: linux, permissions, acl

I have a /home/accounting directory and I need to allow some users to share files without having to change permissions or ownership on any file they put in this directory. 
And then I should restrict read privileges on this directory for one of them.

I suppose I should use ACLs rules but I don't have ideas how to make this works.
Could you please help me?

Comment: See if this helps>>>>>>>https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/access-control-listsacl-linux/

Comment: The problem is: I don't know how to revoke management access from users.
Since they are owners of files by default they have permissions to execute chmod and chown commands on files